# How to query all records changed since date?

Tags: soql, query, sosl

Is there a way to query all records of all object types changed since a given date?  SOQL doesn't appear to have a way to do this.  I thought that the "From" clause might have a way, but when I tried adding a second object onto the query as shown in the SOQL guide:

> FROM objectType[,objectType...][USING [SCOPE filterScope]]

I got the following:

> A driving SObject type has already been set, all other entity types in
>   the FROM clause must be relationships to the initial object.  The
>   driving object is Contact.

SOSL will let you search for specific text within multiple objects, but there doesn't seem be be a way to omit the SearchQuery.

It appears that what I want to do isn't possible, at least with SOQL or SOSL, unless I do one SOQL query per object type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes SOQL  always references concrete SObject types.

But given the ability to find out [all the SObject types](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_global_describe.htm#apex_dynamic_global_describe), the availability of [dynamic SOQL](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) and the [Batchable mechanism](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm) to avoid hitting the "Total number of SOQL queries issued" and "Total number of records retrieved by SOQL queries" [governor limits](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm), a solution should be possible in not too many lines of code.

Comment: I thought I might be overlooking something. Finding out the SObject types was that thing.